# Entropy with infinite baths

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

I'm struggling with the following problem:

(Stephen J. Blundell, Concepts in Thermal Physics S. 154 Problem 14.5):

> A block of lead of heat capacity 1kJ/K is cooled from 200K to 100K in
>   two ways:
>
> a) It is plunged into a large liquid bath at 100K.
>
> b) It is first
>   cooled to 150K in one liquid bath and then to 100K in another.
>
> Calculate the entropy changes in the system comprising block plus
>   baths in cooling from 200K to 100K in these two cases. Prove that in
>   the limit of an infinite number of intermediate baths the total
>   entropy change is zero.

This is my solution so far:

Bath:
$dS = \frac{dQ}{T_{bath}} \Rightarrow \Delta S = \frac{\Delta Q}{T_{bath}} = \frac{C* \Delta T}{T_{bath}}$

Block:
$dS  = \frac{dQ}{T}; C = \frac{dQ}{dT}$

$\Delta S = \int_{T1}^{T2}\frac{C}{T}* dT = C * ln(\frac{T2}{T1})= C* ln(\frac{T2 * T_{m}}{T_{m}*T1}) = C*(ln(\frac{T2}{T_{m}})+ ln(\frac{T_{m}}{T1}))$

in both cases:

$\Delta S_{Block}  = 693,1 \frac{J}{K}$

a) 
$ \Delta S_{bath}  = C * \frac{100K}{100K} = 1000 \frac{J}{K}$

b) $\Delta S_{bath}  =  C* (\frac{50K}{150K} + \frac{50K}{100K} ) = \frac{5}{6}*1000 \frac{J}{K}$

Is this so far correct? I'm struggling with the infinite case:

$ \frac{\Delta S}{C}  = \sum_{i = 1}^N \frac{100K}{n*(200K- i * \frac{100K}{n})}= \sum_{i= 1}^N \frac{1}{2n-i}$

I could not find any solution for $N \rightarrow \infty$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the change in entropy for the block be negative?

Comment: Yes I might have messed up the signs at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the limit of an infinite number of intermediate baths, we can make the approximation that $T_\mathrm{bath} = T_\mathrm{block}$, so for the bath:

$\delta S_\mathrm{bath} = \frac{\delta Q}{T_\mathrm{block}} = -\frac{C\delta T_\mathrm{block}}{T_\mathrm{block}}$

or

$d S_\mathrm{bath} = -\frac{C}{T_\mathrm{block}} d T_\mathrm{block}$

Note that

$\sum_{i= 1}^N \frac{1}{2N-i} = \sum_{i= N}^{2N-1} \frac{1}{i} \approx \int_N^{2N-1} \frac{1}{x} dx \approx \ln 2$

Comment: where can i find more info on the series identity you've given/

Comment: The first identity is just relabling the indices on the sum. Then I recognize that it becomes an integral in the limit of infinite baths, and do the integration.